# Amazon S3 upload with public permissions

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm using the Amazon C# SDK and trying to upload a file, but by default it has restricted permissions.  I would like to make it publicly available, but I can't seem to find out how to do it as part of the upload.

My bucket is public, but when I upload a new file using the code below, the file I upload is not public.

Has anyone had to do this before?

```
public class S3Uploader
{
    private string awsAccessKeyId;
    private string awsSecretAccessKey;
    private string bucketName;
    private Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility transferUtility;

    public S3Uploader(string bucketName)
    {
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        this.transferUtility = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    }

    public void UploadFile(string filePath, string toPath)
    {
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(uploadComplete);
        transferUtility.BeginUpload(filePath, bucketName, toPath, callback, null);
    }

    private void uploadComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    { 
        var x = result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Found it, need to use a `TransferUtilityUploadRequest`:

```
public class S3Uploader
{
    private string awsAccessKeyId;
    private string awsSecretAccessKey;
    private string bucketName;
    private Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility transferUtility;

    public S3Uploader(string bucketName)
    {
        this.bucketName = bucketName;
        this.transferUtility = new Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

    }

    public void UploadFile(string filePath, string toPath)
    {
        AsyncCallback callback = new AsyncCallback(uploadComplete);
        var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest();
        uploadRequest.FilePath = filePath;
        uploadRequest.BucketName = "my_s3_bucket";
        uploadRequest.Key = toPath;
        uploadRequest.AddHeader("x-amz-acl", "public-read");
        transferUtility.BeginUpload(uploadRequest, callback, null);
    }

    private void uploadComplete(IAsyncResult result)
    { 
        var x = result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, you need to specify the `uploadRequest.BucketName` for the upload to work.

Comment: This method of setting the headers has been deprecated after S3 version 1. The `TransferUtilityUploadRequest` object no longer has a `AddHeader` method. The correct answer is now danielonthenet's.

Answer (score 32):

The solution by Tahbaza is correct, but it doesn't work in the later versions of AWS SDK (2.1+)...

Consider using the following for 2.1+ versions of SDK:

```
private void UploadFileToS3(string filePath)
{
    var awsAccessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSAccessKey"];
    var awsSecretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSSecretKey"];
    var existingBucketName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AWSBucketName"];
    var client = Amazon.AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonS3Client(awsAccessKey, awsSecretKey,RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

    var uploadRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
    {
        FilePath = filePath,
        BucketName = existingBucketName,
        CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead
    };

var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(client);
    fileTransferUtility.Upload(uploadRequest);
}
```

Comment: Maybe a little late for OP but please also note that the SDK comes with a range of asynchronous upload and download methods which use the Task Parallel Library.

Usage is : await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(uploadRequest); 

Sample code from Amazon here : http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/net/post/TxPJDGHVNCWHUJ/Amazon-S3-Transfer-Utility-for-Windows-Store-and-Windows-Phone

Comment: Hii Daniel, If I study and use the above code will the uploaded file be private. If I paste the object URL will it say access denied?

Answer (score 5):

I have done this before, and in C#, but not with your library (so this may be of limited help).

The idea is to send an ACL header along with the file.

This is one way to do it that should point you in the right direction.

Here's also a [link](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/index.html?RESTObjectPUTacl.html) to some relevant AWS docs.

```
    private const string AWS_ACL_HEADER = "x-amz-acl";

    private static string ToACLString(S3ACLType acl) {
        switch (acl) {
            case S3ACLType.AuthenticatedRead:
                return "authenticated-read";
            case S3ACLType.BucketOwnerFullControl:
                return "bucket-owner-full-control";
            case S3ACLType.BucketOwnerRead:
                return "bucket-owner-read";
            case S3ACLType.Private:
                return "private";
            case S3ACLType.PublicRead:
                return "public-read";
            case S3ACLType.PublicReadWrite:
                return "public-read-write";
            default: return "";
        }
    }

    public void Put(string bucketName, string id, byte[] bytes, string contentType, S3ACLType acl) {
        string uri = String.Format("https://{0}/{1}", BASE_SERVICE_URL, bucketName.ToLower());
        DreamMessage msg = DreamMessage.Ok(MimeType.BINARY, bytes);
        msg.Headers[DreamHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE] = contentType;
        msg.Headers[DreamHeaders.EXPECT] = "100-continue";
        msg.Headers[AWS_ACL_HEADER] = ToACLString(acl);
        Plug s3Client = Plug.New(uri).WithPreHandler(S3AuthenticationHeader);
        s3Client.At(id).Put(msg);
    }
```

Comment: thx for the help with the headers. I posted my own answer just because its using the standard aws library, which takes advatage of s3 multipart upload,  which allows you to upload chunks of the file asynchronously making it much faster

Answer (score 2):

Consider CannedACL approach, shown in the follwing snippet:

```
        string filePath = @"Path\Desert.jpg";
        Stream input = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
        PutObjectRequest request2 = new PutObjectRequest();
        request2.WithMetaData("title", "the title")
            .WithBucketName(bucketName)
            .WithCannedACL(S3CannedACL.PublicRead)
            .WithKey(keyName)
            .WithInputStream(input);
```

Comment: The AWS SDK marks this approach as deprecated and will be removed in v2.0

Answer (score 2):

You can use the property CannedACL of Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest to upload files to S3 as shown below,

```
 var putObjectRequest = new Amazon.S3.Model.PutObjectRequest
                        {
                            BucketName = bucketName,
                            Key = key,
                            CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicReadWrite
                        };
```