# Paperclip different styles with different permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip

I have a GalleryPhoto model with a paperclip attachment that gets processed into a number of styles. Some styles need to be publicly readable; some need to be private.

Here's my model:

```
class GalleryPhoto < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => ":bucket.myapp_#{Rails.env == 'production' ? 'production' : 'development'}",
    :path => "images/galleries/:gallery_id/:id/:style_:id.:extension",
    :url => "/images/galleries/:gallery_id/:id/:style_:id.:extension",
    :s3_credentials => { :access_key_id => 'XXXXXXXXX', :secret_access_key => 'XXXXXXXXX' },
    :s3_permissions => {
      :thumbnail => :public_read,
      :small => :public_read,
      :medium => :public_read,
      :large => :public_read,
      :small_download => :private,
      :original => :private
    },
    :styles => {
      :thumbnail => {
        :geometry => "80x80>"
      },
      :small => {
        :geometry => "200x200>"
      },
      :medium => {
        :geometry => "400x400>"
      },
      :large => {
        :geometry => "600x600>"
      },
      :small_download => {
        :geometry => "600x600"
      }
    }
end
```

Here's my paperclip initializer:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :bucket do |attachment, style|
  [:original, :small_download].include?(style) ? "private" : "public"
end

Paperclip.interpolates :gallery_id do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.gallery_id
end
```

I have four buckets as such:

```
private.myapp_development
private.myapp_production
public.myapp_development
public.myapp_production
```

The private.xxx buckets shouldn't be publicly accessible, but the public.xxx buckets should be publicly readable.

I can get the app to serve the styles that have been marked public in the public buckets, but I cannot do uploads or have my download action, which serves the private styles, work.

Here's the log when I try to do an upload:

```
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
[paperclip] saving images/galleries/242/22034/original_22034.jpg
   (0.8ms)  ROLLBACK
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 8013ms

Errno::EPIPE (Broken pipe):
  app/controllers/gallery_photos_controller.rb:13:in `create'
```

Here's the log when I try to use my download action for the private styles:

```
Sent file images/galleries/222/19515/original_19515.jpg (0.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 861ms

ActionController::MissingFile (Cannot read file images/galleries/222/19515/original_19515.jpg):
  app/controllers/gallery_photos_controller.rb:22:in `download'
```

What am I missing?

```
rails 3.1.1
paperclip 2.7.0
aws-sdk 1.3.7
```

Comment: Will the lambda work for you? Have a look on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8590822/apply-processor-with-paperclip-if-condition-its-true

Comment: Maybe it is problem with access rights for your new files? Maybe you should set BucketOwnerFullControl option? [for example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616810/amazon-s3-upload-with-public-permissions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paperclip just did not want to store in two buckets with the same attachment. So I separated out the styles into public/private "folders" in the same bucket, with different permissions for each style.

Here's my model code:

```
  has_attached_file :image,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => "myapp-#{Rails.env == 'production' ? 'production' : 'development'}",
    :path => ":bucket/images/galleries/:gallery_id/:id/:style_:id.:extension",
    :url => "/:bucket/images/galleries/:gallery_id/:id/:style_:id.:extension",
    :s3_credentials => { :access_key_id => 'XXXXX', :secret_access_key => 'XXXXXXXXX' },
    :s3_permissions => {
      :thumbnail => :public_read,
      :small => :public_read,
      :medium => :public_read,
      :large => :public_read,
      :small_download => :private,
      :original => :private
    },
    :styles => {
      :thumbnail => {
        :geometry => "80x80>"
      },
      :small => {
        :geometry => "200x200>"
      },
      :medium => {
        :geometry => "400x400>"
      },
      :large => {
        :geometry => "600x600>"
      },
      :small_download => {
        :geometry => "600x600"
      }
    }
```

When I check the permissions on the files in the s3 console, they are appropriate.